# Undo command not working in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a problem with the text widget, where I can't undo anything once the text is cleared.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def clear_text():
    text.delete(1.0 , END)

text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "arial 14" , undo = True)
text.pack()

clear_button = Button(root , text = "Clear" , width = 10 , command = clear_text)
clear_button.pack(pady = 10)

undo_button = Button(root , text = "Undo" , width = 10 , command = text.edit_undo)
undo_button.pack(pady = 10)

text.insert(1.0 , "This is a text widget.")

mainloop()
```

Here, when I click on the clear button and then click on the undo button, the text comes back and everything works fine. But when I click on the clear button one more time, the undo button stops working.

Is there any way to solve this problem? It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: did you try clicking the undo button one time or more than 2 times, seeing that you ran the clear button twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def clear_text():
    text.edit_separator() #Add this line.
    text.delete(1.0 , END)
```

Add a seperator before deleting text, or the undo stack would be empty.